# Angular/Material mat-form-field input - Floating label issue in jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine

I've created a login component in angular using material form controls, such as a form field, that consists of two fields: username and password. Now I want to do unit tests (jasmine) for this component. However, if I run a test with ng test, the material form control will not render correctly. e.g. If you click on the Username field, the label floats up and the user can enter a value.

Can any one suggest how can i render material form controls correctly in jasmine?

login.spec.js

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

  let component: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatButtonModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent
      ]
    })
    .compileComponents()
    .then(createLoginComponent);
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create an instance', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });  

});
```

login.html

```
<form class="mat-form mat-login" *ngIf="loginForm" [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login();">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-icon matPrefix>person</mat-icon>
          <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': loginFormField.username.errors }">
          <mat-error *ngIf="!!loginFormField.username?.errors">
            <span *ngIf="!!loginFormField.username.errors?.required">Username is required</span>
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-icon matPrefix>vpn_key</mat-icon>
          <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Password" [type]="isPasswordVisible ? 'password' : 'text'" formControlName="password"
          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': loginFormField.password.errors }">
          <button type="button" mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible">
            <mat-icon matSufix>{{isPasswordVisible ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
          </button>

          <mat-error *ngIf="!!loginFormField.password?.errors">
            <span *ngIf="!!loginFormField.password.errors?.required">Password is required</span>
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

        <div class="btn-container">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```